# Magento2: How to convert weight unit to grams from kg?

Tags: magento2, database, product-weight, convert, size-weight-units

I have a website in Magento2. Mageto2 provides product weight unit in KG, how an I convert it into unit Gram.

I want to change the product weight unit from KG to Gram how it is possible ?.

Comment: you can debug vendor code